# not able to send E Mail using xampp

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost

Hi I was trying to send Email using php in xammp
I have already started Mercury Service

Heres my code

```
<?php



$to = "nikhil08514@gmail.com";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body="test";

$headers = "From: root@localhost.com"; 

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) 
{
echo "Message successfully sent!";
} 

else

{
echo "Message delivery failed...";
}
?>
```

when i execute code i am getting output as

```
Message successfully sent!
```

But when i check my mail box.I dont see mail.I checked all folders in my Mailbox but its not present

Comment: are you working on a local server? or an online webservice

Comment: Can you please check this code with error_reporting(1),And find what is wrong.May be your smtp_port was not configured

Comment: Actully I have deployed Xampp on my local machine.I Also have internet connectivity active on my machine

Comment: @BhavinRana..I have checked it

Comment: check your `xampp/mailoutput` sending mail usually go there in local machine.. if not properly config.

Comment: it must fire an error ! get ERROR Reporting ON !

Comment: @shin..I include that in script..It didnt give any error...its giving same message "Message successfully sent!"

Comment: @BhavinRana..I have already included "error_reporting(1);" in my script

Comment: @Kaii..Folder you specified is empty

Comment: So the link to the same answer as currently exists is here for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6206356/1745573 The wording in the linked may be more helpful as well.

Comment: @Jon..I checked out the link..But it didnt help

Comment: @nikhil I wasn't sure it would - but thought it might have some use to view - just posted it in two places as the answer should have been a comment with that link alone since nothing useful was added to the answer. ^^

Answer (score 0):

your code is right try that on server it will work surely, xampp does not send directly like that from xammp. by using smtp you can send.